# Extract a value from a nested json key in bash

Tags: bash, sed, terminal, grep

Consider I have the below JSON:

```
{
  "id": "Ab12",
  "details": "{\"timeValue\":null,\"lastModifiedIn\":\"PHX\"}",
  "version": 3
}
```

I want to extract the value of 'lastModifiedIn' key without using the jq command.
Basically, the result I seek for is 'PHX'.

Is there a way to extract this using basic shell scripting?

Comment: Why is `details` a `string` (`"{\"lastModifiedIn\":\"PHX\"}"`) instead of an `object` (`{ "lastModifiedIn" : "PHX"}`)? That makes parsing it harder than necessary. Can you affect the generator of this data somehow?

Comment: that json is actually retrieved from a database call, which store the json as a mere string. I just retrieved it and now I want to extract values

Comment: I'm not too familiar with scripting, but by googling i realized I might have to use grep or sed to extract that value. But, I'm not quite sure how to do it

Comment: If you go that route you'll have to deal with it for every time you extract something from this database. Talk to the database people. Ask them how to extract the json objects properly

Comment: That is true. But, this is more like a hotfix and needs to be resolved from the developers end.

Comment: Do you get just the `detail` string `"{\"timeValue\":null,\"lastModifiedIn\":\"PHX\"}"` in that format or do you get the complete object with `id` and `version` too? If it's just the `details` element, you could use a parser to get it back into its original form.

In python: `print(json.loads("{\"timeValue\":null,\"lastModifiedIn\":\"PHX\"}"))`

Comment: You should really consider making `jq` a requirement if  manipulating JSON from the shell is also a requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sloppy but given the input and your requirement to not use `jq` this might be good enough for your purposes:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*"lastModifiedIn\\":\\"\([^\\]*\).*/\1/p' file
PHX
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. Just curious, instead of 'file' if I want to provide the input through a pipe, how can we do that?

Comment: The same way you do with any other tool: `foo | sed 'script'` instead of `sed 'script' file`.